# When does automatic widening conversion take place in Java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

when exactly does the widening primitive conversion happen in the program?
If I got an expression:

```
long l = 3L;
double d = 5.2L + l;
```

are 5.2L and l converted into double and then calculated, or is the calculation happening in long, with the result being converted to double afterwards?

Comment: Neither. `5.2L` is not a valid literal.

Comment: Oh right. My bad. But which case would happen, if it was 5L instead?

Comment: If it were 5L you would be adding two longs, giving another long, which would then be converted to a double.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what would happen if there was an integer involved? Like "int i = 2; long l = 10; double d = 5L + l / i" Is the term calculated in long or are the variables converted to double first?

Comment: If you add an int and a long, the result will be a long.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code

```
long l = 3L;
double d = 5.2L + l;
```

will not compile because `5.2L` is not a valid literal.

In answer to your further questions:

> which case would happen, if it was 5L instead?

In that case you would be adding two longs, and the result would be a long. That long would be converted to a double if you store it in a `double` variable.

> And what would happen if there was an integer involved?

If you add an int and a long, you get a long. If you are assigning that to a `double` variable, it will subsequently be converted to a double.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `a = b + c` consists of 2 operations:

- Additive Operator `+`

  [JLS §15.18.2. Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) says:

  > Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands ([§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).

  [JLS §5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) says:

  > 2. Widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
  >
  >    - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
  >    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
  >    - Otherwise, **if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`**.
  >    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.
- Assignment Operator `=`

  [JLS §5.2. Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) says:

  > *Assignment contexts* allow the value of an expression to be assigned ([§15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)) to a variable; the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.
  >
  > Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
  >
  > - an identity conversion ([§5.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.1))
  > - **a widening primitive conversion** ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2))
  > - ...

  [JLS §5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) says:

  > 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
  >
  > - `byte` to `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
  > - `short` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
  > - `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
  > - `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
  > - **`long` to `float` or `double`**
  > - `float` to `double`

To re-cap, **first** the `+` operator causes the two operands to be *widened* to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`, whichever first covers both operands. The result of the `+` operator may **then** be further *widened* to fit the variable of the assignment.